# Unexpected character (<) at position 0. while parsing JSON response from HTTP POST request in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, character

I am trying to parse JSON data I receive from POST Http call. I'm using *org.json.simple* library.

Here is the code:

```
String httpsURL = "https://api.clover.com/v3/merchants//orders/19B28B18CMK4C/payments?access_token=4ffcface-fd3b-2e96--48da68fff91f";
URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

String input = "{ \"amount\": \"1099\",\"tender\": {\"id\": \"5680H0J6Y4JCG\"},\"tipAmount\": \"200\"}";

OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();

InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String inputLine; 
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(inputLine);
    //out.println(inputLine);
}

String result = sb.toString();
result = result.replace("Show null fields","");
result = result.trim();
result = result.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

// result = json.replaceAll("\"elements\": ", "");
result = result.replaceAll("\\Q{[\\E", "[");
result = result.replaceAll("\\Q]}\\E", "]");
//out.println(result);

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(result);
String id = (String) jsonObject.get("id");
out.println("The id is: " + id);
```

After Using BufferReader and printing the "result" variable from code. It prints

```
{
    "id": "G6HA2GSJJMBQP",
    "order": {
        "id": "19B28B18CMK4C"
    },
    "tender": {
        "href": "https://www.clover.com/v3/merchants/4B8BF3YJH7P/tenders/5680H0J6Y4JCG?access_token=4ffcfacefd3b2e9611a8da68fff91f",
        "id": "5680H0J6Y4JCG"
    },
    "amount": 1099,
    "tipAmount": 200,
    "createdTime": 1449262033000,
    "clientCreatedTime": 1449262033000,
    "modifiedTime": 1449262033000,
    "result": "SUCCESS"
}Show null fields
```

Can anybody help me to figure out where the problem is?

Error:

> "Unexpected character (<) at position 0."

Sotirios Delimanolis was right.

After reading each character of Inputstream the result is:
< ! d o c t y p e h t m l > < h t m l > < t i t l e > C l o v e r R E S T A P I B r o w s e r < / t i t l e > < h e a d / > < b o d y > < p r e > { & q u o t ; i d & q u o t ; : & q u o t ; V 0 B Z 9 8 X 9 V T V 0 W & q u o t ; , & q u o t ; o r d e r & q u o t ; : { & q u o t ; i d & q u o t ; : & q u o t ; 1 9 B 2 8 B 1 8 C M K 4 C & q u o t ; } , & q u o t ; t e n d e r & q u o t ; : { & q u o t ; h r e f & q u o t ; : & q u o t ; < a h r e f = " h t t p s : / / w w w . c l o v e r . c o m / v 3 / m e r c h a n t s / 4 B 8 B F 3 Y 5 N J H 7 P / t e n d e r s / 5 6 8 0 H 0 J 6 Y 4 J C G ? a c c e s s _ t o k e n = 4 f f c f a c e f d 3 b 2 e 9 6 1 1 a 4 4 8 d a 6 8 f f f 9 1 f " > h t t p s : / / w w w . c l o v e r . c o m / v 3 / m e r c h a n t s / 4 B 8 B F 3 Y 5 N J H 7 P / t e n d e r s / 5 6 8 0 H 0 J 6 Y 4 J C G ? a c c e s s _ t o k e n = 4 f f c f a c e f d 3 b 2 e 9 6 1 1 a 4 4 8 d a 6 8 f f f 9 1 f < / a > & q u o t ; , & q u o t ; i d & q u o t ; : & q u o t ; 5 6 8 0 H 0 J 6 Y 4 J C G & q u o t ; } , & q u o t ; a m o u n t & q u o t ; : 1 0 9 9 , & q u o t ; t i p A m o u n t & q u o t ; : 2 0 0 , & q u o t ; c r e a t e d T i m e & q u o t ; : 1 4 4 9 2 6 4 0 8 6 0 0 0 , & q u o t ; c l i e n t C r e a t e d T i m e & q u o t ; : 1 4 4 9 2 6 4 0 8 6 0 0 0 , & q u o t ; m o d i f i e d T i m e & q u o t ; : 1 4 4 9 2 6 4 0 8 5 0 0 0 , & q u o t ; r e s u l t & q u o t ; : & q u o t ; S U C C E S S & q u o t ; } < / p r e > < p > < a h r e f = " / v 3 / m e r c h a n t s / 4 B 8 B F H 7 P / o r d e r s / 1 9 B 2 8 B 1 8 C M K 4 C / p a y m e n t s ? a c c e s s _ t o k e n = 4 f f a c e - f d 3 b - 2 6 - 1 1 a 4 - 4 8 d a 6 8 f f f 9 1 f & r e t u r n _ n u l l _ f i e l d s = t r u e " > S h o w n u l l f i e l d s < / a > < / p > < / b o d y > < / h t m l >

Comment: What does your response contain? Is it JSON?

Comment: You should really look at JAX-RS, try Jersey, simplifies your application.

Comment: yes , its a JSON response :
<code>{"id": "55GTS63T757E0",   "order": {    "id": "19B28B18CMK4C"  },   "tender": {    "href": "https://www.clover.com/",     "id": "5680H0J6Y4JCG"  },   "amount": 1099,   "tipAmount": 200,   "createdTime": 1449189804000,   "clientCreatedTime": 1449189804000,   "modifiedTime": 1449189804000,   "result": "SUCCESS"} Show null fields</code>

Comment: Can you show use your POST Http call

Comment: I don't believe you. Consume the inputstream and print it out.

Comment: @user1486269 Please edit your post and add the additional information instead of posting code in the comments.

Comment: Okay... I edit the post .. with the full code ... and the result when I only print the Inputstream